# Customize celery with rate limit and workers cuncurrency per group

Tags: python, celery

I have a simple python celery task:

```
@app.task
def simple_task(key, i):
    print('start', key, i)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 1.5))
    print('finish', key, i)

...

def call_simple_tasks():
    for key in ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']:
        for i in range(10):
            simple_task.apply_async(args=[key, i])
```

Is it possible to customize celery queue (with routing_key or something else) with two conditions:

- Only X tasks with the same key could be executed at the same time (per group of tasks with the same key)
- Tasks rate limit must be 2/s per key (for each group with the same key tasks can't be started more frequently than 2 tasks per second)

I found `rate_limit` property for task but it doesn't allow limit per key.